Levels of factor variable not displayed correctly by #tbl_summary
I have two factor variables (PCR, freezing) each with two levels and NAs.
> class(test_dat$Freezing)
[1] "factor"
> class(test_dat$PCR)
[1] "factor"

> summary(test_dat$Freezing)
  No  Yes NA's 
  36   13    7 

> summary(test_dat$PCR)
negative positive     NA's 
      26       25        5 

I want to  create a table with tbl_summary()
>test_dat |> select(Freezing, PCR) |> tbl_summary()

And it prints this:

The levels of the variable Freezing are not showed correctly. It should be 3 levels (No, Yes, NAs).
If I create a 2x2 table with the two variables, it works well, and levels are shown correctly, but I want to display them also independently.
> test_freezing <- test_dat |> select(PCR,Freezing)
> test_freezing  |> tbl_summary(by=Freezing)|>  add_p()



If you want missing values included in frequency counts, make the variables a factor including the NA values as a proper factor level, e.g. forcats::fct_na_value_to_level(c("a", NA), level = "Missing")
